# Do blog comments count as updates to your website?

Tags: seo, google, blog

I constantly hear that websites which are updated frequently do better in terms of SEO, so I was wondering: do blog comments count? I'm guessing they do, since they show that the website still has a 'lifeblood' to it - but I thought it'd be wise to check here first.

Comment: The term you want to research is fresh content. Comments are not treated as page freshness but are classed as an updates, in the linked question which is more appropriate there's an article in one of my answers which covers this grounds. Telling you what counts as freshening the page, what classes as updating, and how considerable importantly these elements are.